# How are multiple objects in a single JSON file separated?

Tags: json

I'm working with a RESTful API which returns JSON messages... however there's a certain amount of guesswork involved as the API isn't available yet. I have an approximate spec, but it misses a few details for which I'm currently assuming the API uses standard/default/"normal" behaviour to allow myself to get a prototype completed

One of these unknowns is that I'm expecting multiple items back in the file when making a request, but I'm not sure how this will work... how does JSON handle multiple files in one object? Is there a standard, or at least a best practice?

Is it as simple (and obvious) as a comma delimited array? ie

```
[ {object 1}, {object 2}, {object 3} ]
```

Or is it not held in an array at all, merely delimited with commas or naturally: ie

```
//Comma separated
{object 1}, {object 2}, {object 3}
//Or naturally delineated
{object 1}{object2}{object3}
```

Or perhaps an array within an object?

```
{ [ {object 1}, {object 2}, {object 3} ] }
```

This may be obvious, and my assumption would be that it's a comma delimited array as per my first example, but I can't quite work out from the documentation I've found whether arrays can be the container, or whether they can only exist inside another object.

I'm unable to check with the API provider at the moment, and I'm prepared for the fact they may use a completely different technique to "standard", but since I'm sat twiddling my thumbs I'd rather try the most likely/standard technique, and be prepared to change it if necessary

Comment: Type "JSON spec" into google. And use a reliable library to generate or process JSON data.

Comment: I won't be generating the JSON data, I'll be receiving it and passing it on (I'm developing an interface which is mostly data-agnostic... I just have to separate the items out)

Comment: Why would you imagine that a JSON API might return invalid JSON? If it does that's just a bug in the API. ALso, JSON doesn't handle "files"; perhaps you mean "objects"? You left out the most obvious and likely alternative, which is `{ thing1: { }, thing2: { }, thing3: { } }`. Anyway, it sounds like you need to work out your workflow with your manager/client. Just tell them that you can't start working until you have a spec, period. Why would you want to waste time shooting at a moving target, or in this case not just moving but invisible?

Comment: Because the bulk of the work involves things around the JSON, with a tight deadline - if we have to rework it then we lose nothing, but if we get it right it relieves a lot of pressure. Also in 15 years of development I've learned never to assume an API will even use the expected markup, never mind the correct standard... But I figure that's the best to work to when stabbing in the dark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should expect something like one of these:

```
[ { ... }, { ... }, { ... } ]

{ "items": [ { ... }, { ... }, { ... } ] }
```

You should *not* expect something like one of these:

```
{ ... }, { ... }, { ... }

{ ... }{ ... }{ ... }
```

These are *not* valid JSON and you should not accept them if you are in a position to influence an API that is still under construction. If the response content type is going to be `application/json`, it had better be giving you valid JSON bytes.

The right way to do this is simply to do your `GET /some/resource/collection` and then inspect the JSON response.

Comment: Thanks, there isn't currently a response to check - hence the question - but at least this gives me something to start to work from.